# How to drop an array of T by its length and *mut T?

Tags: rust, ffi

Please do not mark the question as duplicate of [casting *mut u8 to &[u8] without std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941427/casting-mut-u8-to-u8-without-std). I need a review of my idea.

Let me introduce the context of this question.

Consider the following C++ code, in order to drop the array of pointers, we need to

```cpp
void foo() {
    T ** array_of_pointers = ...;
    size_t size_of_array = ...;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++) {
        delete array_of_pointersp[i];
    }
    delete [] array_of_pointers;
}
```

However, in Rust, we can also build the above `array_of_pointers`. You may ask why bother? However, I want to use it as a mock for some FFI codes which I will leave out to make this question simple and direct.

Here is my code. I have a `RawCppPtr` which is a wrapper of `T*`(which is not an array), and a `RawCppPtrArr` which is a wrapper of `T**`(which is an array of `T*`). In this code, I will assume `T` to be String. So I can create a String with `gen_cpp_string` and put it into a `Vec<RawCppPtr>`. Then I convert `Vec<RawCppPtr>` into `*mut [RawCppPtr]`, and finally into `*mut RawCppPtr`. I know little about Fat/Thin pointer, so `*mut [RawCppPtr]` is a fat pointer with array length, and `*mut RawCppPtr` is a thin pointer which point to the first element of array(am I right?).

```rust
pub struct RawCppPtr {
    pub ptr: *mut std::os::raw::c_void,
    pub type_: u64,
}

impl Drop for RawCppPtr {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        assert_eq!(self.type_, 1);
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::<Vec<u8>>::from_raw(self.ptr as *mut Vec<u8>));
        }
    }
}

extern "C" fn gen_cpp_string(s: &[u8]) -> RawCppPtr {
    let str = Box::new(Vec::from(s));
    let ptr = Box::into_raw(str);
    RawCppPtr {
        ptr: ptr as *mut _,
        type_: 1,
    }
}


unsafe impl Send for RawCppPtrArr {}

pub struct RawCppPtrArr {
    pub inner: *mut RawCppPtr,
    pub len: u64,
}

impl Drop for RawCppPtrArr {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            let len = self.len;
            // Delete all `T**`
            for i in 0..len {
                let i = i as usize;
                let inner_i = self.inner.add(i);
                drop(inner_i);
            }
            // Delete `T*`
            drop(self.inner);
            self.inner = std::ptr::null_mut();
            self.len = 0;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let len = 10;
    let mut v: Vec<RawCppPtr> = vec![];

    for i in 0..len {
        let s = format!("s{}", i);
        v.push(gen_cpp_string(s.as_bytes()));
    }

    let box_v = v.into_boxed_slice();
    // Convert from *mut [RawCppPtr] tp *mut RawCppPtr
    let ptr_va = Box::into_raw(box_v);

    println!("va {}", std::mem::size_of_val(&(ptr_va))); // 16 which means a fat pointer
    let ptr_v = ptr_va as *mut RawCppPtr;
    let cpp_ptr_arr = RawCppPtrArr {
        inner: ptr_v,
        len: len as u64,
    };

    println!("v {}", std::mem::size_of_val(&(ptr_v))); // 8 which means a thin pointer
    drop(cpp_ptr_arr);
}
```

If I am right, the code leaks memory. All `String`s are dropped, however, the array of `RawCppPtr` is not correctly dropped. I should drop `*mut [RawCppPtr]` rather than `*mut RawCppPtr` to free this array.

I want to know how to correctly drop this array, which `*mut RawCppPtr` and the length of the original `*mut [RawCppPtr]`.

Please note that I don't want to use `*mut [RawCppPtr]` because I am writing FFI codes. C++ doesn't has something like fat pointers.

==== UPDATE ====

After some searching, I find some from_raw_parts functions may help. However, I don't know if this is the best practice. And I also need some review of my whole idea.

A little more explanation about the FFI. In my program, Rust do knows when to drop `RawCppPtr`. However, Rust do not know how to drop `RawCppPtr`, since it is created by C++. So when Rust wants to drop `RawCppPtr`, it will call by a FFI function, and the C++ part of my program will delete `RawCppPtr` by checking its type. This scene make sense, for example if the `RawCppPtr` is used as a context which held by Rust, but only meaningful to C++. When Rust no longer need to call C++, it will drop the `RawCppPtr`.

Comment: Yes `from_raw_parts` is the way to go, but just the length isn't enough info to properly free it, you need the capacity as well.

Comment: @cafce25 I use `into_boxed_slice` rather than `into_raw_parts`, do I still need capacity?

Comment: @cafce25 By looking at source code of `into_boxed_slice`, I found it will call `shrink_to_fit`, which seem to make capacity equals len

Comment: No, it makes `capacity` >= but as close to `len` as possible. Wich might be `len` but might also be a little bit more, depending on the allocator. See the docs of `shrink_to_fit`. And yes you need to call `from_raw_parts` with the `capacity` the pointer was allocated with.

Comment: `capacity` refers to how much memory was allocated, whereas `size` to how much memory is currently used (and therefore how many objects within the array must be freed). If you allocated as much memory as you use, you can give `size` as the `capacity`. Otherwise, you need to pass this information as well. Besides, about fat / thin pointers, it's true that `*mut [T]` contains the pointer and the size, whereas `*mut T` only contains the pointer.

Comment: Also, it is good practice to transform things given through FFI into owned Rust types **if you truly want to have ownership**, and leave it to them to deallocate the memory.

Comment: @jthulhu I don't know how to do that, because the ownership is kind of "broken". Rust actually owns the `RawCppPtr`. I mean Rust do knows when to drop `RawCppPtr`. However, Rust do not know how to drop `RawCppPtr`, since it is created by C++. So when Rust wants to drop `RawCppPtr`, it will call by a FFI function, and the C++ part of my program will delete `RawCppPtr` by checking its `type`. This scene make sense, for example if the `RawCppPtr` is used as a context which held by Rust, but only meaningful to C++.

Comment: @cafce25 Thanks you for pointing out this. Meanwhile, is it correct if I use `into_boxed_slice` to get a `*mut RawCppPtr`, and use its `len` as argument for `from_raw_parts`?

Comment: I'm struggling with how to answer this question, because `from_raw_parts[_mut]` gets you most of the way there and an answer could simply address the question of `Box<[T]>` -> FFI -> `Box<[T]>` -> `Drop` as a whole. However, I'm distracted by your FFI layer itself; `gen_cpp_string` appears to be your attempt, but the types used in it are not FFI-safe, the compiler even warns you about this. And its not clear to me which parts of the code are supposed to be Rust-under-test and which are Rust-mocking-C++... So its hard for me to address the "ownership" and "review of my idea" parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Linux (or Windows with WSL), you can use the LLVM ASAN to find out if your code leaks memory.

First, install the `llvm` package and add a nightly toolchain:

```bash
sudo apt install llvm
rustup install nightly
```

Then, clean and rerun your program on nightly with `-Z sanitizer=address`:

```bash
cargo clean
RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitizer=address" cargo +nightly run
```

In your case, this is what I get:

```
va 16
v 8

=================================================================
==1163==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 160 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x56160fa4f7a6 in realloc /rustc/llvm/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:85:3
    #1 0x56160fa82606 in alloc::alloc::realloc::hb51e4854c2cd558e /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:132:14
    #2 0x56160fa82606 in _$LT$alloc..alloc..Global$u20$as$u20$core..alloc..Allocator$GT$::shrink::h33a2c7a85dc19dd0 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:300:31
    #3 0x56160fa91e99 in alloc::raw_vec::RawVec$LT$T$C$A$GT$::shrink::h992b7dbe07a9cc09 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:434:13
    #4 0x56160fa8f0b2 in alloc::raw_vec::RawVec$LT$T$C$A$GT$::shrink_to_fit::hdabc7b2f8734a8b2 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:353:24
    #5 0x56160fa7a7c1 in rust_tmp::main::hb0e8c33aaec1d192 /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/main.rs:58:17
    #6 0x56160fa8833a in core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h59579e65705d84ac /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:507:5
    #7 0x56160fa77104 in std::rt::lang_start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hfe28e02ef7178702 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:166:18
    #8 0x56160faa694b in core::ops::function::impls::_$LT$impl$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$A$GT$$u20$for$u20$$RF$F$GT$::call_once::ha21c39ffd5fcb6b0 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:606:13
    #9 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::do_call::hfcb5b7de6a967aa4 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:483:40
    #10 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::h852b554f2a216a1e /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:447:19
    #11 0x56160faa694b in std::panic::catch_unwind::h138950e22f10d85b /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
    #12 0x56160faa694b in std::rt::lang_start_internal::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h0de24c6b40b0e960 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
    #13 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::do_call::hd6b16c5e5da3ce3b /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:483:40
    #14 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::hb7de684c95f0cf1d /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:447:19
    #15 0x56160faa694b in std::panic::catch_unwind::h8cc7b91a0a2687e5 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
    #16 0x56160faa694b in std::rt::lang_start_internal::hf69e88a76ee34b77 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20

Indirect leak of 120 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x56160fa4f37e in malloc /rustc/llvm/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69:3
    #1 0x56160fa7f599 in alloc::alloc::alloc::h65ebcea6dc0f57fc /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:95:14
    #2 0x56160fa7f599 in alloc::alloc::Global::alloc_impl::h3020a89bee822f51 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:177:73
    #3 0x56160fa7e904 in _$LT$alloc..alloc..Global$u20$as$u20$core..alloc..Allocator$GT$::allocate::he4c810c1d4972785 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:237:9
    #4 0x56160fa7e904 in alloc::alloc::exchange_malloc::h2608191d7b8c8b30 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:326:11
    #5 0x56160fa79d17 in alloc::boxed::Box$LT$T$GT$::new::hf0594a7f872c5b56 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:220:9
    #6 0x56160fa79d17 in rust_tmp::gen_cpp_string::h631935a5fa641aec /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/main.rs:16:15
    #7 0x56160fa7ab33 in rust_tmp::main::hb0e8c33aaec1d192 /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/main.rs:55:16
    #8 0x56160fa8833a in core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h59579e65705d84ac /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:507:5
    #9 0x56160fa77104 in std::rt::lang_start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hfe28e02ef7178702 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:166:18
    #10 0x56160faa694b in core::ops::function::impls::_$LT$impl$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$A$GT$$u20$for$u20$$RF$F$GT$::call_once::ha21c39ffd5fcb6b0 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:606:13
    #11 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::do_call::hfcb5b7de6a967aa4 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:483:40
    #12 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::h852b554f2a216a1e /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:447:19
    #13 0x56160faa694b in std::panic::catch_unwind::h138950e22f10d85b /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
    #14 0x56160faa694b in std::rt::lang_start_internal::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h0de24c6b40b0e960 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
    #15 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::do_call::hd6b16c5e5da3ce3b /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:483:40
    #16 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::hb7de684c95f0cf1d /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:447:19
    #17 0x56160faa694b in std::panic::catch_unwind::h8cc7b91a0a2687e5 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
    #18 0x56160faa694b in std::rt::lang_start_internal::hf69e88a76ee34b77 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20

Indirect leak of 10 byte(s) in 5 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x56160fa4f37e in malloc /rustc/llvm/src/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69:3
    #1 0x56160fa7f599 in alloc::alloc::alloc::h65ebcea6dc0f57fc /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:95:14
    #2 0x56160fa7f599 in alloc::alloc::Global::alloc_impl::h3020a89bee822f51 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:177:73
    #3 0x56160fa832e0 in _$LT$alloc..alloc..Global$u20$as$u20$core..alloc..Allocator$GT$::allocate::he4c810c1d4972785 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:237:9
    #4 0x56160fa8ebef in alloc::raw_vec::RawVec$LT$T$C$A$GT$::allocate_in::hae911a4c2fb5959f /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:185:45
    #5 0x56160fa87703 in alloc::raw_vec::RawVec$LT$T$C$A$GT$::with_capacity_in::h6636278b38918562 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:131:9
    #6 0x56160fa87703 in alloc::vec::Vec$LT$T$C$A$GT$::with_capacity_in::hdeada21f93fcb1dc /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:673:20
    #7 0x56160fa87703 in _$LT$T$u20$as$u20$alloc..slice..hack..ConvertVec$GT$::to_vec::h1fd64ee8d4bb65f9 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/slice.rs:157:25
    #8 0x56160fa86a34 in alloc::slice::hack::to_vec::ha41d09eef56ea4e4 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/slice.rs:106:9
    #9 0x56160fa86a34 in alloc::slice::_$LT$impl$u20$$u5b$T$u5d$$GT$::to_vec_in::h16897712ae3feab3 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/slice.rs:436:9
    #10 0x56160fa86a34 in alloc::slice::_$LT$impl$u20$$u5b$T$u5d$$GT$::to_vec::h3d1191f6fd4dcfe0 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/slice.rs:411:9
    #11 0x56160fa86a34 in _$LT$alloc..vec..Vec$LT$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$$u5b$T$u5d$$GT$$GT$::from::hb85a3961450a1d84 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:3118:9
    #12 0x56160fa79d08 in rust_tmp::gen_cpp_string::h631935a5fa641aec /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/main.rs:16:24
    #13 0x56160fa7ab33 in rust_tmp::main::hb0e8c33aaec1d192 /home/finomnis/work/rust-tmp/src/main.rs:55:16
    #14 0x56160fa8833a in core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h59579e65705d84ac /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:507:5
    #15 0x56160fa77104 in std::rt::lang_start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::hfe28e02ef7178702 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:166:18
    #16 0x56160faa694b in core::ops::function::impls::_$LT$impl$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$A$GT$$u20$for$u20$$RF$F$GT$::call_once::ha21c39ffd5fcb6b0 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:606:13
    #17 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::do_call::hfcb5b7de6a967aa4 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:483:40
    #18 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::h852b554f2a216a1e /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:447:19
    #19 0x56160faa694b in std::panic::catch_unwind::h138950e22f10d85b /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
    #20 0x56160faa694b in std::rt::lang_start_internal::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h0de24c6b40b0e960 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
    #21 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::do_call::hd6b16c5e5da3ce3b /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:483:40
    #22 0x56160faa694b in std::panicking::try::hb7de684c95f0cf1d /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panicking.rs:447:19
    #23 0x56160faa694b in std::panic::catch_unwind::h8cc7b91a0a2687e5 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
    #24 0x56160faa694b in std::rt::lang_start_internal::hf69e88a76ee34b77 /rustc/af3e06f1bf4ca49407562b1b84744e27905bea98/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 290 byte(s) leaked in 11 allocation(s).
```

---

Now about the actual fixing.

There are several misconceptions you have:

- `drop(inner)` does **NOT** delete the object `inner` is pointing to, it only deletes the pointer
- `generate_cpp_string` does **not** generate a C/C++ compatible string object.
  It generates a pointer to a `Vec`, which C/C++ knows absolutely nothing about. You probably want to create a boxed slice here as well.
- If you use `RawCppPtr` as a type in a `extern 'C'` function, it has to be FFI safe. The same goes for `&[u8]`, which also isn't FFI safe.
- I understand that you only use `Vec<u8>` as a dummy type, but don't do that, it is not compatible with C. Use something C compatible like `f32` for demonstration purposes. Especially because you can't convert `*mut u8` back to a slice and free it without knowing its length. Or use a custom C-compatible struct that stores both the pointer and the length.
- If you intend `gen_cpp_string` to be called from Rust only, don't declare it `extern "C"`. Only declare the functions that shall be called from C `extern "C"`.

Let's first approach the fact that you can't undo the conversion from `*mut [u8]` to `*mut u8`. One is a fat pointer and the other one is thin, so you need to store the size somewhere to convert back.

To achieve that, let's store it in a C compatible struct:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct CString {
    data: *mut u8,
    len: usize,
}

impl CString {
    pub fn copy_from_slice(s: &[u8]) -> Self {
        let boxed_slice = Vec::from(s).into_boxed_slice();
        let len = boxed_slice.len();
        let data = Box::into_raw(boxed_slice);
        Self {
            data: data.cast(),
            len,
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for CString {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(
                self.data, self.len,
            )));
        }
    }
}
```

Next, let's talk about `RawCppPtr`. For that one, your implemention seems to be mostly correct. All I did was replace `Vec<u8>` with the C-compatible `CString` and add `#[repr(C)]` to make the struct layout FFI compatible:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct RawCppPtr {
    pub ptr: *mut std::os::raw::c_void,
    pub type_: u64,
}

impl Drop for RawCppPtr {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        assert_eq!(self.type_, 1);
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(self.ptr as *mut CString));
        }
    }
}

fn gen_cpp_string(s: &[u8]) -> RawCppPtr {
    let str = Box::new(CString::copy_from_slice(s));
    let ptr = Box::leak(str) as *mut CString;
    RawCppPtr {
        ptr: ptr.cast(),
        type_: 1,
    }
}
```

Now about `RawCppPtrArr`: There are several problems here.

For one, I highly discourage creating an unsafe struct outside if its own implementation. Your code in `main` that creates this struct should be a member function of it.

Further, the way you drop it doesn't actually do anything. You need to convert it back from pointers to actual objects. Dropping pointers does not actually drop the things they point to. The easiest, like in `CString`, is to use `from_raw_parts`:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct RawCppPtrArr {
    pub inner: *mut RawCppPtr,
    pub len: u64,
}

impl RawCppPtrArr {
    pub fn from_vec(v: Vec<RawCppPtr>) -> Self {
        let box_v = v.into_boxed_slice();
        // Convert from *mut [RawCppPtr] tp *mut RawCppPtr
        let len = box_v.len() as u64;
        let ptr_va = Box::into_raw(box_v);
        let ptr_v = ptr_va as *mut RawCppPtr;
        Self { inner: ptr_v, len }
    }
}

impl Drop for RawCppPtrArr {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(
                self.inner,
                self.len as usize,
            )));
        }
    }
}
```

Now all together, with `main` adjusted accordingly, we get:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct CString {
    data: *mut u8,
    len: u64,
}

impl CString {
    pub fn copy_from_slice(s: &[u8]) -> Self {
        let boxed_slice = Vec::from(s).into_boxed_slice();
        let len = boxed_slice.len() as u64;
        let data = Box::into_raw(boxed_slice);
        Self {
            data: data.cast(),
            len,
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for CString {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(
                self.data,
                self.len as usize,
            )));
        }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct RawCppPtr {
    pub ptr: *mut std::os::raw::c_void,
    pub type_: u64,
}

impl Drop for RawCppPtr {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        assert_eq!(self.type_, 1);
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(self.ptr as *mut CString));
        }
    }
}

fn gen_cpp_string(s: &[u8]) -> RawCppPtr {
    let str = Box::new(CString::copy_from_slice(s));
    let ptr = Box::leak(str) as *mut CString;
    RawCppPtr {
        ptr: ptr.cast(),
        type_: 1,
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct RawCppPtrArr {
    pub inner: *mut RawCppPtr,
    pub len: u64,
}

impl RawCppPtrArr {
    pub fn from_vec(v: Vec<RawCppPtr>) -> Self {
        let box_v = v.into_boxed_slice();
        // Convert from *mut [RawCppPtr] tp *mut RawCppPtr
        let len = box_v.len() as u64;
        let ptr_va = Box::into_raw(box_v);
        let ptr_v = ptr_va as *mut RawCppPtr;
        Self { inner: ptr_v, len }
    }
}

impl Drop for RawCppPtrArr {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            drop(Box::from_raw(std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(
                self.inner,
                self.len as usize,
            )));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let len = 10;
    let mut v: Vec<RawCppPtr> = vec![];

    for i in 0..len {
        let s = format!("s{}", i);
        v.push(gen_cpp_string(s.as_bytes()));
    }

    let cpp_ptr_arr = RawCppPtrArr::from_vec(v);
    println!("v {}", std::mem::size_of_val(&(cpp_ptr_arr.inner))); // 8 which means a thin pointer
}
```

No need to `drop(cpp_ptr_arr)`, this happens automatically at the end of `main()` with all local variables.

Now if we run it again with the sanitizer:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitizer=address" cargo +nightly run
v 8
```

And no leaks.

---

### **Important**: One more caveat

Converting a `&str` to a `&[u8]` does **NOT add a trailing zero** and the resulting byte slice is **NOT C compatible**. There is an easy fix, however: Replace the `CString` struct we wrote with the compiler built-in [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html). This one handles zero terminations correctly.